# Get the coordinates from ContourPlot and RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, export

How do I get the coordinates from a contour plot I've done in *Mathematica*? For example, I have a two-variable function `f[x, y]`, for which I can make a contour plot:

```
    contour = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
```

I can access a nested list, containing lists of coordinates, from an exported file using

```
    Export["output.m", contour, "TEXT"]
```

but the nested list is inside the function `Graphics`.

I would like to export only the corresponding nested list. What is a straightforward way to do that? Is there a way of doing that by manipulating directly the variable `contour`?

**Edit**

@Jens solution was

```
    Cases[Normal@contour, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]
```

Is there a way to generalize it? The issue is that `Line` won't give us the points inside a region. E.g., I would like to get the coordinates corresponding to a region plot:

```
    region = RegionPlot[f[x, y] > 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
```

Comment: Your edit is an entirely different question, it seems to me. What do you expect to get? A grid of points? How dense?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it would be wrong to open another post for a very similar question. I would like to get the coordinates associated to the region shown by a region plot. As dense as the `RegionPlot` output.

Comment: Now I understood what you mean (I think), so I updated the answer.

Comment: @Jens, do you think I should change the title to _Get the coordinates from ContourPlot and RegionPlot_?

Comment: Sure, that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the plot usually is a `GraphicsComplex`, the extraction is easiest if you first convert using `Normal`:

```
contour = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];

Cases[Normal@contour, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]
```

This produces a list that shows the coordinates in the order they were drawn.

**Explanation:**

The contours in the plot are drawn using the `Line` command, which takes lists of points (or lists of lists of points). Usually, these points are all collected at the front of the `ContourPlot` output in the form of a `GraphicsComplex`, such that each point can later be addressed by using an index from within the `Line` commands. By applying `Normal`, these indexed points are moved to where they are actually used in the drawing part of the output. `Normal@contour` is the same as `Normal[contour]`.

After that is done, we can look for all `Line` commands and find the coordinates in sequential order inside of them. This is done by using [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html), which selects parts of the expression that match a pattern. The pattern is specified here as `Line[x_]` where `x_` is a "dummy variable" that gets defined whenever a `Line` was found, by replacing it with the contents of the line. The final step is to tell `Cases` that when it does find a value for `x`, to just output that without the wrapper `Line`.

This search is done throughout the whole plot, which is indicated by the `Infinity` level specification.

**Update for `RegionPlot`**

Extracting points from a plot using `Cases` can be generalized to situations where the points aren't inside a `Line`. In `RegionPlot`, for example, you may want to extract the points that form the mesh with which the region is filled. This filling is done by a polygonal tesselation, so we have to simply replace `Line` with `Polygon`:

```
region = Normal@RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
pts = DeleteDuplicates@
   Flatten[Cases[region, Polygon[x_] :> x, Infinity], 1];

Graphics[Point[pts]]
```

[image: points]

Here I had to add two more steps before being able to make the plot: first, `Flatten` is used to remove all nested levels except the ones grouping the coordinate tuples for each point. Then, I added `DeleteDuplicates` just to remove any shared vertices between polygons, so one and the same point isn't re-drawn redundantly.

Comment: Please, could you explain the syntax?

Comment: OK, I've added an explanation and slightly simplified the expression.

Comment: Thanks. What if `ContourPlot` has two or more functions as arguments (e.g., `{f[x,y],{g[x,y]}}`)? How should we change the code above?

Comment: I assume you mean two equations of the type `{f==1, g==1}`? It should work without modification, and the order of the lines lets you determine which equation they belong to. The output of `Cases` is a list of lists, so the structure of the point sets is preserved.

Comment: Yes, I meant `{ f[x,y] == 1, g[x,y] == 1}`. But it would be more convenient to make two distinct nested lists, one for each function.

Comment: Then just take the list as above, call it `l`, and access the first list as `l[[1]]`, the second list as `l[[2]]` etc. If that doesn't work for you, it's always possible to generate two separate contour plots to be sure you capture the correct coordinates.

Comment: Hi @Jens, do you know how `Normal` orders the points? I have a plot with a series of contours and using this function gives me some contours with points ordered from left to right and others from right to left, is there a way to make this consistent?

Comment: No, and I wouldn't rely on any undocumented feature even if the order were coincidentally following some pattern. You should just sort them to be certain. It's easy using `SortBy[... , First]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here the answer for @Luiz Roberto Meier, which was closed although it was no duplicate, but needed some deeper reflections.

First, ContourPlot doesn't show the complete solution.

This plot is complex-valued, therefore you may use `Re` and `Im`

So, the extraction of the plotpoints in ContourPlot won't be very useful, but as already suggested it might be done of course using Cases:

```
points = ContourPlot[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0}, 
    {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}] // Normal // Cases[#, Line[$_] -> $, Infinity] &
ListPlot[points, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 5]
```

Basically the two functions can be solved by

```
Clear@"`*"
f[x_] := x^3
g[x_] := Block[{y}, y /. Solve[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0 }, y]]

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> 5, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: plotWithoutReal]

f is easy, so we concentrate on g from now on.
Inspecting g we find that it has 4 complex solutions in y, (order 4)

Plotting g using `Plot` having a look at Re and Im gives:

```
Clear@"`*"
g[x_] := Block[{y}, y /. Solve[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0 }, y]]
Plot[{g[x][[1]], g[x][[2]], g[x][[3]], g[x][[4]]} // Re // 
  Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> 5, AspectRatio -> 1]
Plot[{g[x][[1]], g[x][[2]], g[x][[3]], g[x][[4]]} // Im // 
  Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> 5, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: plotWithReal]
[image: plotWithIm]

Let's say, we are interested in the real part.
In the plot we see that we are missing some points for x near -2.5
As we are interested in a complete point list, we try increasing option values like MaxRecursions or PlotPoints (without success).

Changing strategy using ListPlot, where we can increment ourself the x-Range provides
a high quality solution and a complete set of {x,y} point coordinates by analytical means:

```
Clear@"`*"
g[x_] := Block[{y}, y /. Solve[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0 }, y]]
sol1 = Re@{#, g[#][[1]]} & /@ Range[-5, 5, .005];
sol2 = Re@{#, g[#][[2]]} & /@ Range[-5, 5, .005];
sol3 = Re@{#, g[#][[3]]} & /@ Range[-5, 5, .005];
sol4 = Re@{#, g[#][[4]]} & /@ Range[-5, 5, .005];
ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> 5, 
   AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ {sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4}
ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> 5, AspectRatio -> 1] &@{sol1,
   sol2, sol3, sol4}
```

Of course it would be possible to map over the 4 solutions at once but for the sake of explanation I didn't.

the first image shows the solutions separated,
the next image combines them.

[image: listplotsSeparated]

all  points for the complete real solution you were looking for `g[x]`, are now in:

{ sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4 }