# How many times do the two given curves intersect at the origin?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm reading/studying on my own a book about algebraic curves.

I'm trying to find a way for *Mathematica* help me with the following (the book, ISBN: 038731802X, allows me to use any CAS / program.

Here is a question:

> How many times do the two given curves intersect at the origin?
>
> $\quad(a)\quad y = x^3$
>
> which I can rewrite as $y-x^3 = 0$
>
> $\quad(b)\quad y^4 + 6x^3*y + x^8 == 0 $

I can view both curves using:

```
ContourPlot[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0, y - x^3 == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

However, I have no idea how to find the the multiplicity of the zeros at the origin. I'm really stuck.

Comment: ContourPlot doesn't show the complete solution, I answered your recent question for the point coordinates in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20281/get-the-coordinates-from-contourplot-and-regionplot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Count[Solve[y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0 /. {y -> x^3}], {x -> 0}]

(* 6 *)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can explicitly see that the degree of intersection at $(0,0)$ is $6$ using:

```
p1 = y - x^3; 
p2 = y^4 + 6 x^3 y + x^8;
Factor[p2 /. y -> x^3]
```

Also revealing is:

```
Factor @ GroebnerBasis[{p1, p2}, {y, x}]
```

Giving

```
{x^6 (x^6 + x^2 + 6), y - x^3}
```

This result is connected to Bézout's Theorem (covered in your textbook).

Comment: I like the way you think.

Comment: This is my favorite solution among all the ones offered. Gröbner bases are very useful!

Answer (score 11):

#### General approach

If `{x0, y0}` is a root of a polynomial system `{p1, p2}` such that there is no other root of the form `{x0, y1}`, the multiplicity is given by the multiplicity of the zero `x0` of the resultant

```
Resultant[p1, p2, y]
```

We can compute the multiplicity of this zero with

```
SparseArray[
   CoefficientList[Resultant[p1, p2, y] /. x -> x0 + u, u]
 ]["NonzeroPositions"][[1, 1]] - 1
```

If a root `{x0, y0}` lines up with another root `{x0, y1}`, a linear transformation of the variables can always be found so that moves all the other roots off the line `x = x0`.  So in principle, this method can be applied to any system.

**OP's example**

In the OP's case, the command can be simplified a little since `x0 == 0`:

```
SparseArray[
   CoefficientList[Resultant[y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8, y^2 - x^3, y], x]
 ]["NonzeroPositions"][[1, 1]] - 1
(*
  6
*)
```

#### Comparison

I assume the OP wants a method, not just the answer.  (The OP's is simple enough to do, plug in `x^3` for `y`, in one's head after all.)  We compare the `NSolve` method and [@belisarius's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius) `Solve` method with the `Resultant` method.

My original method was to use `NSolve`, which seems to work *although the docs do not promise that it will*, like this if we add `Count` as @belisarius did:

```
Count[NSolve[{p1 == 0, p2 == 0}, {x, y}], {x -> 0.`, y -> 0.`}]
```

Generalizing @belisarius's answer, I would get something like

```
Count[Solve[p1 == 0 /. #, x, Reals] & /@ Solve[p2 == 0, y] // Flatten, x -> 0]
```

which indeed yields `6` on the OP's example.

**A more difficult example**

Now let's consider the system with `y^2` replacing `y` in the second polynomial:

```
p = {y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8, y^2 - x^3};
```

The two solve-based methods give different answers:

```
Count[NSolve[p == {0, 0}, {x, y}], {x -> 0.`, y -> 0.`}]
(* 9 *)

Count[Solve[p[[1]] == 0 /. #, x, Reals] & /@ Solve[p[[2]] == 0, y] // Flatten, x -> 0]
(* 10 *)
```

One solution gets counted twice in the `Solve` method, I guess, because the `Resultant` method yields

```
SparseArray[CoefficientList[Resultant[p[[1]], p[[2]], y], x]]["NonzeroPositions"][[1, 1]] - 1
(* 9 *)
```

**Failure on repeated x0 - and the workaround**

If we add some factors to the OP's system so that `{x, y} = {0, 1}` is a root, all the current solutions fail to yield `6`:

```
p = {(y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8) (x^2 + (y - 1)^2), (y - x^3) (y - 1)};

Count[NSolve[p == {0, 0}, {x, y}], {x -> 0.`, y -> 0.`}]
(* 3 *)

Count[Solve[p[[1]] == 0 /. #, x, Reals] & /@ Solve[p[[2]] == 0, y] // 
  Flatten, x -> 0]
(* 8 *)

SparseArray[CoefficientList[Resultant[p[[1]], p[[2]], y], x]]["NonzeroPositions"][[1, 1]] - 1
(* 8 *)
```

Edit: Actually `NSolve` gets close, literally.  Numerical error leads to three of the roots being slightly off:

```
Count[Chop[NSolve[p == {0, 0}, {x, y}], 10^-50], {x -> 0, y -> 0}]
(* 6 *)
```

One can also use the `Resultant` method by transforming the coordinates so that the root `{0, 1}` is moved off the line `x = 0`:

```
With[{p = p /. {x -> x + y, y -> y}},
 SparseArray[CoefficientList[Resultant[p[[1]], p[[2]], y], x]]["NonzeroPositions"][[1, 1]] - 1]
(* 6 *)
```

Simply switching `x` and `y` also works in this case.

---

*Orginal answer -- `NSolve` gives the correct multiplicity in V10*

`NSolve` will return the multiplicity, which turns out to be 6 in this case:

```
NSolve[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0, y - x^3 == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
(*
  {{x -> 0., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.},
   {x -> 0., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}}
*)
```

(I included a solution using `Eliminate` but it's not worth the space it would take up.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, Michael.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Could you help me understand why `Solve` would only return one set of `{x -> 0., y -> 0.}`?

Comment: @seismatica the command returned the following:

{{{x -> 0, y -> 0}, 1}} :( I'm going crazy with this issue.

Comment: @seismatica I'm using exactly (copy/past) and even typping the exact commands. Only the command of belisarius worked so far.

Comment: @seismatica Now, ALL the commands (only the first one works, from belisarius : 

[link](http://snag.gy/851N3.jpg)

Comment: @seismatica without the Reals *all* solutions worked and if I need to 'filter' I just use {x->0. ,y->0.} . If I remove from your Tally[stuff] the Reals, also, I get the entire values and the last value is our 6.

Tally@NSolve[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0, y - x^3 == 0}, {x, y}]

(*
{{{x -> 0. - 1.27842 I, y -> 0. + 2.08941 I}, 
  ... 
  1}, {{x -> 0., y -> 0.}, 6}}
*)

Comment: @LuizRobertoMeier The learning curve for Mathematica is rather steep. See for example http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/459/193

Comment: @LuizRobertoMeier From m_goldberg's answer, it's clear that you probably have MMA version 9 or older.

Comment: Michael, @Luiz, et al., the comments are a bit excessive in number.  Would you please incorporate any important points into the question or answer proper, and remove many of these?

Comment: @MichaelE2, et al., I deleted four or five comments. A last question about this. The DSolve return a list in this format: {x -> -1., y -> -1.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.} how can I force or modify the list to return {-1., -1.}, {0., 0.} ? The reason I need it is because I wish to see where the two (or more) curves intersect using Point to mark it in the ContourPlot. I'm using version 10 now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LuizRobertoMeier See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706

Answer (score 10):

This is not an answer, but is too long for a comment. `NSolve` produces different results for

```
NSolve[{y^4 + 6 x^3*y + x^8 == 0, y - x^3 == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

according to the *Mathematica* version it is evaluated in.

In V9, it produces

> ```
> {{x -> 0, y -> 0}}
> ```

while in V10 it produces

> ```
> {{x -> 0., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.},
>  {x -> 0., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}}
> ```

In my opinion, the V10 result is clearly to be preferred.

Comment: Does `Solve` have different results between these two versions? I don't have MMA 9 to compare.

Comment: I am with all working fine with my update to V10. Also I notice that in V9 I can get the same answers when I don't explicitly use Reals and instead I use Tally[] and/or Select[] to filter '0.' instead of 0 Also, the study of curves isn't only about (0.,0.) but where n curves will touch m times , including projective geometry (curves / objects / points going to infinity).