# Extracting data from Plot

Tags: plotting

I have a parametric matrix. I can solve the eigenvalue problem as a function of the parameter used in the matrix. I need to extract the solutions as a function of the parameter. Let me give an example: Suppose I have a parametric matrix as

```
m[c_] := {{1, -c + 1, 2}, {c, 5, c}, {2, 5, c}};
```

The eigenvalues can be plotted as a function of the parameter using

```
Plot[Eigenvalues[m[c]], {c, 0, 1}]
```

which results

[image]

Now I want to extract data of these plots. How can I do that functionally using Mathematica's commands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to extract data of these plots

There are many ways to extract data from plots (if you search you'll find good examples).

One method I like is `EvaluationMonitor` since one can then control what data to extract, and how to format it, even thought it might not be the most efficient?

```
ClearAll[m, c, x]
m[c_] := {{1, -c + 1, 2}, {c, 5, c}, {2, 5, c}};
data = Reap@
   Plot[Eigenvalues[m[c]], {c, 0, 1}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{c, Eigenvalues[m[c]]}]];
data = data[[2, 1]]
```

And now data contains what you want

```
 {{2.04082*10^-8, {5., 2.56155, -1.56155}}, 
  {0.0196287, {5.04462, 2.52608, -1.55108}}, 
  {0.0409084, {5.09137, 2.48926, -1.53972}}, 
  ....
```

The first value in each row is `c` and the second list in each row are the eigenvalues for that `c`.

For example

```
 Eigenvalues[m[0.0196286612015304`]]
```

Gives

```
 {5.04462, 2.52608, -1.55108}
```

Which you see is the second row in the output. etc..

The above is basically the same as doing

```
 Table[{c, Eigenvalues[m[c]]},{c,0,...}]
```

The only difference is that you are using `Plot` choice of the sample values of `c` it used to make the plot, which one does not know before hand.

**Update**

> It is not possible to plot data of each line

All the data is there. One way to plot it from the extracted data is

```
p1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2, 1]]}], PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2, 2]]}], PlotStyle -> Blue];
p3 = ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2, 3]]}], PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[{p1, p2, p3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is probably a better way to plot the data back, but this becomes a question on plotting. The point is, all the data is there.

Comment: Dear @Nasser,It is not possible to plot data of each line if I extract data of each line using your method.

Comment: @HS8637 it is possible. Since all the data is there. I'll post how.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you just want to create functions for each eigenvalue:

```
{eig1[c_], eig2[c_], eig3[c_]} = Eigenvalues[m[c]];
```

Plot:

```
Plot[{eig1[c], eig2[c], eig3[c]}, {c, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The value of the second eigenvalue at $c=2$:

```
eig2[2]
```

> 4 - Sqrt[11]

Answer (score 4):

Following [this answer by @Jens](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20282/6358):

```
plot=Plot[Eigenvalues[m[c]], {c, 0, 1}];
points=Cases[Normal@plot,Line[x_]:>x,\[Infinity]];
ListPlot[points]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]