# Getting a list of accurate coordinates from a ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, coordinate

I have a set of functions `d=d(b)` defined implicitly by the equation

`f(b,d)=0.`

I have plotted that equation using `ContourPlot`. The problem is that I need to get the coordinates drawn in the plot (or maybe get the coordinates using only the equation) in an accurate way. I have already seen this question:

[Getting a list of accurate coordinates from a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14222/getting-a-list-of-accurate-coordinates-from-a-plot)

but it seems that the solutions only solve the problem when you use the `Plot` function. Also, I have tried to use drawing tools, but that doesn't seem so accurate and I would like to get the coordinates of all the points in the plot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47899122/10426870) answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20281/get-the-coordinates-from-contourplot-and-regionplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Cases` idea that's usually used with `Plot` (see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19860/46490)) if you first send the contour plot (read: `GraphicsComplex`) through a `Normal`.

```
Normal@ContourPlot[Norm@{x, y} == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
Cases[%, Line[data_] :> data, \[Infinity]][[1]]
```

{{0.0690086,-0.99758},<<261>>,{0.0690086,-<<17>>}}

Comment: Perhaps a little bit simpler: `ContourPlot[Norm@{x, y} == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}][[1]][[1, 1]]`