# Get the coordinates from RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, export

I have a plot generated with RegionPlot3D and need to extract the coordinates of the points on the plot. I'm trying to apply the approach from [this question about RegionPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20281/get-the-coordinates-from-contourplot-and-regionplot) to RegionPlot3D but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

I am also open for any other suggestions on how to extract the coordinates. Ideally I want as many as possible and in csv (I need to pass it to the Elsevier visualisation tool)

```
region3d = Normal@RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]

pts = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Cases[region3d, Polyhedron[x_, y_] :> {x, y}, Infinity], 1]
```

The last lines gives an empty list and I'm not sure how to fix it. I suppose the problem is with Polyhedron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RegionPlot3D produces a GraphicsComplex, whose first argument is the list of coordinates. So you can use

```
pts = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}][[1, 1, 1]];
```

You can then export these points, e.g., to a csv file.
Or plot them, e.g.,

```
ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
pts1=Cases[region3d, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity]
```

Or

```
pts2 = DeleteDuplicates@
  Cases[region3d, Polygon[{pts__}, Rule[VertexNormals, __]] :> pts, 
   Infinity]
```

```
Graphics3D[Point@pts2]
```

[image]